# Ошибка при запуске sql-скрипта из командной строки

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование

Решил запустить скрипт `bookorama.sql`:

```
create table customers
( customerid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name char (30) not null,
address char(40) not null,
city char(20) not null
);
create table orders
( orderid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
customerid int unsigned not null,
amount float(6,2),
date date not null
);
create table books
( isbn char(13) not null primary key,
author char(30),
title char(60),
price float(4,2)
);
create table order_items
( orderid int unsigned not null,
isbn char (13) not null,
quantity tinyint unsigned,
primary key (orderid, isbn)
);
create table book_reviews
(
isbn char (13) not null primary key,
review text
);
```

с помощью команды

```
    > mysql -h host -u root books -p < bookorama.sql;
```

и получил ошибку как на скриншоте

[image]

```
ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -h localhost -u root books p < bookorama.sql' at line 1
```

[[@Чад](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4)](/users/7390/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B4) , [[@uzumaxy](/users/1015/uzumaxy)](/users/1015/uzumaxy) я пытался также выполнить `"C:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\bin> mysql -h localhost -u root books -p < bookorama.sql;"` - быстро прокручивало экран - как будто выдавало подсказку по опциям. Далее пытался заходить в консоль mysql, выполнял команду `use books`, а затем `show tables`, на что выдавало

```
Empty set(0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

[image]

Comment: @Чад пишет то же самое: - быстро прокрутило экран - как будто выдавало подсказку по опциям.

Answer (score 3):

Наверное стоит запускать эту команду из командной строки системы а не из командной строки mysql?

Comment: @Чад если запускать команду из командной строки системы, а не из командной строки mysql, то выдает ошибку

    "mysql" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
(см. команду)

Comment: @ivan89, А как вы запустили сам mysql?

Comment: А если так: "C:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\bin\mysql -h host -u root books -p < bookorama.sql;" ?

Comment: @Чад , @uzumaxy я предварительно перешел в папку `C:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\bin`, затем выполнил команду `mysql -h localhost -u root`, потом `use books`, а далее пробовал команды `mysql -h host -u root books -p < bookorama.sql;`и `mysql -h localhost -u root books -p < bookorama.sql;`, на что выдавало одну и ту же ошибку.

Comment: @Чад , @uzumaxy я пытался также выполнить `"C:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\bin> mysql -h localhost -u root books -p < bookorama.sql;"` - быстро прокручивало экран - как будто выдавало подсказку по опциям. Далее пытался заходить в консоль mysql, выполнял команду `use books`, а затем `show tables`, на что выдавало

    Empty set(0.00 sec)

    mysql>

Comment: Я думаю Вам надо в bookorama.sql первой строчкой добавить 
  
    use books;

Comment: @Чад не помогло.

Comment: Таки что пишет после выполнения скрипта?

Answer (score -1):

```
cd C:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\bin    
mysql -h localhost -u root books -p < bookorama.sql
```

Точку с запятую, после последней строчки, ставить не нужно.